# How to pass an argument to custome provider using ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, provider, ninject-extensions

I have a service called `MyRepository`, I was to write my own custom provider for `MyRepository`. How can I pass an argument to the constructor of `MyRepository` using the provider?

This is my code:

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private string _path;

    public MyRepository(string path)
    { 
        _path = path;
    }

    // more code...
}

public class MyRepositotyProvider : Provider<IMyRepositoty>
{
    public static IMyRepositoty CreateInstance()
    {
        return new MyRepository(/*how to pass an argument?*/);
    }

    protected override IMyRepositoty CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        // I need to pass path argument?
        return CreateInstance();
    }
}

// I need to pass the path argument to the provider
var instance = OrganisationReportPersisterProvider.CreateInstance(/*pass path arg*/);
```

Comment: Is the string a constant or some value extracted from setting? Or is it something dynamic and sent as part of the request to create the instance? I need more information to understand the context of the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi, thanks for your comment the string is a setting value in app.config. The provider is at a lower layer of application and does not have access to the app.config... I could move this setting value to a lower layer (e.g. define it as a constant in the same project that the provider is)... but I was wondering if I could pass it as an argument to the provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you could consider using an abstraction that can be passed to lower layers

```
public interface ISomeSetting { 
    string Path { get; } 
}
```

and can then be resolved via the context in the provider

```
public class MyRepositotyProvider : Provider<IMyRepositoty> {

    public static IMyRepositoty CreateInstance(string path) {
        return new MyRepository(path);
    }

    protected override IMyRepositoty CreateInstance(IContext context) {
        ISomeSetting setting = context.Kernel.Get<ISomeSetting>()
        var path = setting.Path;
        return CreateInstance(path);
    }
}
```

The implementation will live in a higher layer and allows for decoupling.

Ideally the repository could have been refactored to depend on the abstraction

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository {
    private readonly string _path;

    public MyRepository(ISomeSetting setting)  
        _path = setting.Path;
    }

    // more code...
}
```

and avoid the need to have a provider to begin with.